# How to Integrate an Angular Application into a Monorepo with Bazel?

Tags: angular, ngrx, bazel, angular-universal, monorepo

I've spent the last weeks building a Typescript monorepo, which can be built and deployed to Kubernetes using Bazel. But the final piece of the puzzle is **integrating an Angular application** in to the whole workflow, which I'm really struggling with.

## The Project

```
 ├── WORKSPACE
 ├── BUILD.bazel
 ├── package.json
 ├── packages
 │   ├── package1
 │   ├── package2
 │   └── package3
 └── services
     ├── service1
     ├── service2
     ├── service3
+    └── angular-app
```

- `WORKSPACE` file in the root
- `BUILD.bazel` file in the root
- only one `package.json` in the root
- all packages/services are Typescript libraries
- services depend on packages
- every package/service has its own `BUILD.bazel` file

[Source code](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/tree/c992514f458ff9588f90ebb077b603ad359989c3)

## Goal

In the end I want to be able to add a `k8s_object` for the Angular app to the root `BUILD.bazel` file like this:

```
 load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:objects.bzl", "k8s_objects")
 k8s_objects(
     name = "kubernetes_deployment",
     objects = [
         "//services/service1",
         "//services/service2",
         "//services/service3",
+        "//services/angular-app"
     ]
)
```

and it should deploy the Angular app to Kubernetes when I run `bazel run :kubernets_deployment.apply`. Just like the other services which already work perfectly. The deployment process involves:

- creating source code bundles
- creating a Docker image
- pushing the Docker image a registry
- applying changes to Kubernetes cluster

## Challenges

1. Add Angular Bazel dependencies to my existing [`WORKSPACE`](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/c992514f458ff9588f90ebb077b603ad359989c3/WORKSPACE) file
2. Make it possible to import my local [packages](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/tree/c992514f458ff9588f90ebb077b603ad359989c3/packages) into my Angular source code via `import { something } from '@project/package1';`
3. All NPM dependencies should be added to the root [`package.json`](https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/blob/c992514f458ff9588f90ebb077b603ad359989c3/package.json) instead of the one in the Angular project
4. Integrating [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) (my Angular app uses NgRx for state management)
5. Integrate [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) (for server-side-rendering)
6. Integrate Angular PWA (progressive web app)
7. Setup a local development server

## What I've Tried

#### rules_nodejs Angular Example

I was surprised to find a working example of something that is akin to my project: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/master/examples/angular. But as it turned out the structure of their monorepo is somewhat different. They also use `scss`, which I am not and there are not integrations for NgRx or Angular Universal. So I've tried to use it a template by I just couldn't make it work.

#### Bazel with Angular CLI

Of course I've also tried the documented way of adding Bazel to Angular: https://angular.io/guide/bazel, which seems to work for a clean project. With `ng build --leaveBazelFilesOnDisk` it is event possbile to access the Bazel files. But I got errors telling me that NgRx and my local packages could not be found.

---

## Update

I've gone through the first steps of setting everything up on a clean angular project: https://github.com/flolu/cents-ideas/tree/4d444240cbbe2f8b015c4b7c85746c473bc6842b/services/client
But I get an error I am not able to resolve:

```
ERROR: /home/flolu/Desktop/cents-ideas/services/client/src/app/BUILD.bazel:5:1: Compiling Angular templates (Ivy - prodmode) //src/app:app failed (Exit 1)
external/npm/node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2421:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppRoutingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2421 export declare class RouterModule {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/npm/node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2421:22 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of AppRoutingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2421 export declare class RouterModule {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/npm/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts:44:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/platform-browser) which declares BrowserModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

44 export declare class BrowserModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app-routing.module.ts:11:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

11 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Florian, great progress so far :)

I suggest just looking closely onto bazel-related files in that angular example and copying all needed rules / functions to your project. The files are `.bazelrc`, `WORKSPACE`, `BUILD.bazel` (in every subfolder), `rules_docker.patch` (it's applied on http_archive in WORKSPACE).

Also, several very important files in `/src` folder (they are used in the BUILD file): `rollup.config.js`, `rxjs_shims.js`, `main.dev.ts`, `main.prod.ts`. And there are two `index.html` files in the `example` folder: one for prod and one for dev.

Btw, this example already contains ngrx, so it may be a good fit for you, just look closely at `ng_module` rules in BUILD files and their deps. Just add your deps there (smth like `@npm//@ngrx/store`, etc).

As for Angular Universal, looks like it's not well supported by Bazel now. Here is the issue to track: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/issues/1126

And as for scss, that's cool if you use simple css, then you can just insert it into `assets` field of `ng_module` and you don't need to add additional compilation steps from rules_sass (sass_binary, sass_library). Just ignore them when copying rules from the example.

On the project structure, here is my example of migration from Nx to Bazel: https://github.com/scalio/nx-bazel-starter.
It's a bit outdated, so better to orient on the official one. But you may find some useful features there, i.e. how folders are structured in the Nx. Actually the idea is very similar to yours: they just call services as apps, packages as libs and share common `package.json`.

Comment: Sounds really good! I will come back to it at the end of the week :) At the meantime: any idea on integrating Angular Universal/PWA manually?

Comment: Well, there is a PR from Toxicable: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/pull/1173
Not sure if it works actually. Maybe you can try smth similar.

Comment: To fit the structure of my monorepo I will probably need to move all NPM dependencies from the `package.json` in the angular app to the root of the project. Do you think this will cause issues? (e.g. when updating angular to a newer version in the future)

Comment: Yes, I think you should. Another option is to have WORKSPACE in each app folder but not sure if it works well in terms of sharing the code.
I don't think it will cause any issues because I saw relatively big codebases that follow one-package.json-in-the-root approach and it worked good. The good outcome here also is that you won't have many node_modules folders which intersect almost fully. Actually Nx (which is a good example to follow TS monorepo practices) follow this approach. Here is the related discussion in their github: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1777

Comment: I did not got it working yet, but with I think I am on the right path now, thank you!

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you would take a look at the error I've added to my question. I am kind of stuck

Comment: Hey man, sorry, had a hectic week. I pulled the repo and found out what's missing: you should add a post-install step in package.json to run ngcc compiler for angular-related dependencies in node_modules. Here how it looks like: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/examples/angular/package.json#L72

Comment: Also, if you have an error similar to this: "We recommend updating to Bazel 2.1 or greater", either upgrade rules_nodejs in WORKSPACE file or add .bazelversion file with "2.1.1" content (there is a bug for old versions of rules_nodejs and the latest version of bazel).

Comment: I wouldn't know what I would do without you! Aside from a few errors in the browser console it works!

Comment: Is it possible to use `ibazel` with `bazelisk`? (I don't want to install Bazel manually on my system)